# C++ returning value

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

The following C++ code outputs:

```
$ g++ -O3 c.cpp
$ ./a.out 
in func: 0x7fff5c1ecaf8
in main: 0x7fff5c1ecaf8
hello
```

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct C {
    string s;
};

C f() {
    C c = {.s="hello"};
    cout << "in func: " << &c << endl;
    return c;
}

int main() {
    C obj = f();
    cout << "in main: " << &obj << endl;
    cout << obj.s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions regarding the code and output above:

1. in the function `f`, `c` is created on the stack, and upon returning `c`, the caller in `main` got a copy of `c`, is it correct?
2. if "Yes" is the answer to question 1, why the memory address of `c` in `f` is the same as the memory address of `obj` in `main`, as they are both `0x7fff5c1ecaf8` in the output?

Comment: A very simple optimization by the compiler called [*copy elision*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Why should the compiler make an actual copy if none is needed?

Comment: Thanks. So is it considered bad practice to write code like and and to rely on the compiler optimization?

Comment: No, this is the way you should usually do it IMO.

Comment: It's certainly bad practice to use C99 constructs like .`s="hello";` in C++ code, and not to include the correct header files for the Standard Library features you are trying to use.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm a C++ newbie, that's the way I initialize a struct ever since. So what is the recommended way? Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, function call might have been inlined, i.e. there is no return and stack address is actually the same as in main. Check disassembly.

Comment: Also note that compiler, OS and hardware do not execute the program that you write. They execute a program that is *equivalent* to yours in observed side effects (e.g. console printout).

Comment: @Drop that kind of annoying, does it mean even my code is wrong, it works?

Comment: @Elgs I strongly doubt your C++ textbook told you to use that syntax. You are using a GCC extension. To diagnose faults like that use some extra compiler options like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen it can be, sure. Check e.g. [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Have linked to a question that explains what's going on.  It'd be nice if C++ did support designated initializers for aggregates, and/or named parameters for constructors